# Image size getting bigger while print using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, printing

I am writing code to print ID Card so for that I have written print a specific 'div' using javascript, print operation working correctly but problem came with the Image on the ID card it is getting bigger on the print window. My code is below

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="printDiv('id-card')" value="print" />

<div class="x_content">
  <?php foreach ($idcard_reports as $key => $value) {
          $img_path = base_url("assets/images/user.png");
          if($value->photo!=''){
           $img_path = base_url("assets/images/uploads/".$value->photo);
          } ?>
  <div class='id-card' id='id-card'>
    <h3>School Name</h3>
    <img src="<?php echo $img_path?>" class='id-card-img'>
    <div class='id-card-inside-content'>
      <p><span><b>Name</b></span> : <?php echo $value->preferred_name; ?></p>
      <p><span><b>Register No</b></span> : <?php echo $value->register_no; ?></p>
      <p><span><b>Class</b></span> : <?php echo $value->class; ?></p>
      <p><span><b>Section</b></span> : <?php echo $value->section; ?></p>
      <p><span><b>Roll</b></span> : <?php echo $value->roll_no; ?></p>
      <p><span><b>Blood Group</b></span> : <?php echo $value->blood_group; ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php  } ?>
```

**Javascript**:

```
function printDiv(divName) {
   var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
   var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
   document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
   window.print();
   document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

**CSS**:

```
.id-card{
 border:1px solid black;
 width:257px;
 height:290px;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
}
.id-card img{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  max-width:100%
}
.id-card .id-card-inside-content{
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #id-card, #id-card * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #id-card {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

**Screenshot for ID card to be printed**:
[image]

**After clicks on the 'print' button, the print screen will be like below**:
[image]

**My Goal** is to print Image on the ID Card normally as a user before clicks on the 'print' button. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use a media query `@print` and define a max-width for the image.

Comment: I have shared my css code please suggest some css code too along with the media query & also the ID cards would be single (or) multiple also, please check my question as I updated.

Comment: bro, I have googled it already & used media query but its not working

Comment: I don't see any media query attempt in your example. Your kind of questioning looks like asking for letting somebody else doing your homework.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to update media query, now I have updated my question with media query in the css section. please check it

Comment: Could you please help me? @MarkusZeller Anyone help me?